# Node.js: Cannot find 'data', 'end' event in http.IncomingMessage in docs

Tags: node.js

We always write:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    req.on('data', function(){})
       .on('end', function(){});
});
```

But the problems is: I can't find any breath of `Event: data` or `Event: end` in `Class: http.IncomingMessage` in https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html

Please tell me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the documentation for [HTTP.IncomingMessage](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), it says:

> It implements the Readable Stream interface, as well as the following additional **events**, methods, and properties.

If you check the [Stream.Readable](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) documentation, you can find `Event: 'data'` and `Event: 'end'`.